# How to apply the quotient rule to total differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm currently working through some gaps in my knowledge surrounding total differentiation. When the equation is fairly simple, I'm fine. But I get lost when it comes to apply rules like quotient rule or chain rule.

$$ y=\frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} $$

If someone could walk me through this, I'd appreciate it because I'm confident that I'm doing solving it incorrectly.
\begin{align}dy&=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1}\,dx_1 + \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_2}\, dx_2 \\
&= \frac{1}{(x_1 + x_2)^2} (1-1)\, dx_1 + \frac{1}{(x_1 + x_2)^2} (1-0)\, dx_2
\end{align}
Please help me.

Comment: $\frac{\delta y}{\delta x_i}$ is a rather unusual notation for $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}$

Comment: Oh geez. Good catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, I think you are just confusing what is a variable and what is "constant" in the partials. For $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1}$, we consider $x_2$ as a constant, so we have

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1}=\frac{1(x_1+x_2)-x_1(1+0)}{(x_1+x_2)^2}=\frac{x_2}{(x_1+x_2)^2}.$$

With this in mind, you should be able to find $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_2}$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go through this with me. $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_2} = \frac{0(x_1 + x_2) - x_1(1)}{(x_1 +x_2)^2} = \frac{-x_1}{(x_1 + x_2)^2}$

Comment: @soph yes, that’s correct!

Comment: I think my biggest mistake was not thinking of the total differential as just a combination of the partial derivatives. Once I got over that mental hurdle, it's much easier. Thank you again

Comment: @soph Happy to help. If you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left.